# How to call multiple js functions on document.ready without putting them jQuery(document).ready(function(){});

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to 'bind' multiple functions to jQuery's document.ready function without actually calling them in that method. Basically I don't know which functions I might be calling in document.ready until the page is generated.

Comment: What do you mean "bind without calling"? Do you want them to get called on ready or not?

Comment: Erm, why would you not know? Isn't it something you should be using an `if` statement for or just delaying the assignment to `$(document).ready()` (which will cause the function to either delay execution until the page is loaded or, if it's already loaded, execute)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this.  (You probably want #2.)

1. Use an options class to determine
   what happens, then have static code
   which checks the options to see
   which functions to call.
2. Wait until you know what functions
   to call, and add each of them into
   $(document).ready(*whatever*) as
   separate lines.

   > ```
   > $(document).ready(function1);
   > $(document).ready(function8);
   > ```
3. Dynamically create the body of the one function you write into $(document).ready(...)

Comment: Yeah I'll go with #2, didn't now you could call document.ready multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If you call $(document).ready() anytime after the document was *already* ready, it will just execute immediately: (http://jsfiddle.net/Ew8b3/)

```
var afterReady = function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('body').append('<div>waited 5 secs</div>');
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(afterReady, 5000);
});
```

I'm not sure how/when you *will* know what you want to execute, but know that you can use document.ready at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean by bind without calling. But what you can do is pass the functions in as variables (for example func1, and func2)

this way you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
                      var func1 = ...;
                      var func2 = ...;
                      doSomething(func1,func2);
}

doSomething(f1,f2){
   return f1()+f2("somedata");
   // or whatever you wanna do
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function() { alert('ready'); });
```

is the same as

```
Jquery(document).ready(function() { alert('ready'); }):
```

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question.